# Server moved,got error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I had a laragon installed on my laptop. Now I'm on an other one where is running Ubuntu. I moved evertyhing,but I got an error:

> [2018-04-22 11:51:34] local.ERROR:
>   DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::registerBreadcrumbs():
>   Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\proba1\routes/breadcrumbs.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 64):
>   DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::registerBreadcrumbs():
>   Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\proba1\
>   outes/breadcrumbs.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') at
>   /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/src/BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php:92)
>   [stacktrace]
>
> ## 0 {main} "}  [2018-04-22 11:53:41] local.ERROR: DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::registerBreadcrumbs():
>
> Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\proba1\routes/breadcrumbs.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 64):
>   DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::registerBreadcrumbs():
>   Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\proba1\
>   outes/breadcrumbs.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') at
>   /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/src/BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php:92)
>   [stacktrace]
>
> ## 0 {main} "}

After this log,I got a now folder in a basic folder of the laravel. I tried,maybe a definied variable,with this path,but nowhere. Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

Managed. I had to delete the

> cache

files from the

> /bootstrap/cache

folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

create these folders under storage/framework:

sessions
views
cache

Answer (score 0):

Same error, I deleted files inside bootstrap/cache, except .gitignore and run in CLI

```
    composer dumpautoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Image [Showing problem in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp5T4.png)
**Problem Statement**

```
 require()
 vendor\davejamesmiller\laravelbreadcrumbs\src\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php:94
```

DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::registerBreadcrumbs()          vendor\davejamesmiller\laravelbreadcrumbs\src\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider.php:63

```
**Solution of this Problem that works 100%**

Remove files from the cache folder inside the bootstrap folder and run composer dump-autoload. It will work.
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this `artisan` command on your projects root directory:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: :| just run in your Terminal.